# Get let ledger wise Dr and Cr from sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table structure of the Journal Voucher.

Table Name : JvDetails

Here i enterd two JVs.

```
VID LedgerID    Dr   Cr   DrOrCr Sno
1   Cash A/c    500  NULL   Dr   1
1   Sales A/c   NULL 500    Cr   2
2   Salary1     500  NULL   Dr   3
2   Salary2     500  NULL   Cr   4
2   Cash A/c    NULL 1000   Cr   5
```

and my ledger wise output will be
if I query Cash A/c

```
Ledger      Dr   Cr
Sales A/c   500  NULL
Salary1     NULL 500
Salary2     NULL 500
```

if I query Sales A/c

```
Ledger      Dr   Cr
Cash A/c    NULL 500
```

if I query Salery1

```
Ledger      Dr   Cr
Cash A/c    500  NULL
```

Can anyone help me to create the SQL view or Stored Procedure Or Function to produce this ledger wise result

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  If you are querying "sales" why would the results only be "cash"?

Comment: In VID 1 two ledgers involved one is Cash and another one is Sales if i query sales it will return all records against that sales. The entries may be Sales and Bank or Sales and Cheque so the result will be all Cash,Bank,Cheque with the respective amount if i query sales.

Comment: . . Such logic is incredibly not obvious and should be completely described in the *question* and not in a *comment*.